# Плавная инкрементация числа

Tags: actionscript-3

Задача - инкрементить число за определеное время, допустим, нужно к 100 добавить 200 к примеру, за 250мс. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: первый простой, сторонняя библиотека, например greensock tween - https://greensock.com/tweenlite-as // TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:330}); второй через таймер, с шагом в 30мс

Comment: @ShockWave, можно поподробней о таймере с шагом 30мс?

Comment: примерно так - http://pastebin.com/CBAPx6YL - если это графический объект и ему надо менять координату, то лучше через твинер

Comment: @ShockWave, у меня задача постоит в том, что когда сервер присылает координаты обьекта, я должен этот обьект сдвинуть с старой точки к новой(что прислал сервер), и если просто менять координаты, будет очень не красиво, обьект грубо говоря телепортируется. И мне нужно все точки(x,y,z) плавно сдвигать к новым. Надеюсь правильно обьяснил

Comment: ну да, твинер идеально подходит

Comment: @ShockWave спасибо, буду пробывать

Comment: если что в скайпе (swa512) или чате быстрее, по почте долго отвечаю